# XML schema: How to override abstract element inherited from abstract type

Tags: inheritance, xsd, abstract

I know the title is probably confusing. Here's some XSD to try to illustrate:

First some abstract types:

```
<complexType name="ConfigurationBaseType" abstract="true">
  <attribute name="id" type="ID" use="required"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="TransportBaseType" abstract="true">
  <sequence>
    <element name="configuration" 
             type="msg:ConfigurationBaseType" 
             maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

A concrete implementer of `TransportBaseType`:

```
<complexType name="ActiveMQTransportType">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="msg:TransportBaseType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="broker" 
                 type="msg:ActiveMQBrokerType" 
                 maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element name="destination" 
                 type="msg:ActiveMQDestinationType" 
                 maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

I have another type that is a concrete implementer of `ConfigurationBaseType` that I'd like to "plug in" as the `configuration` element inherited from `TransportBaseType`.

Is there a way to do this in XML schema? Any suggestions or alternate methods are welcome.

Comment: A couple of turns of phrase in the question make it hard to understand what you are trying to say.  First, note that despite what the title of the question says, the `configuration` element in your abstract TransportBaseType is not abstract.  Second -- you want to plug in a *type* where an *element* is?  (Do you mean you would like to derive a type from TransportBaseType in which the configuration elements have a particular type?

Comment: How is it that the `configuration` element is not abstract?  It's type is the abstract type `ConfigurationBaseType`?  What I want to do is plug in a concrete implementer of the abstract type (`ConfigurationBaseType`) for the `configuration` element of `ActiveMQTransportType` which is itself a concrete implementer of the abstract type `TransportBaseType`.

Comment: The element is not abstract because (and in the sense that) its declaration does not carry the attribute-value specification `abstract="true"`.  Element != type.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen others trying what you've described; since you've asked questions related to Java, I'll use Java references, and then illustrate with XSD.

Without limiting, let's assume in Java that your abstract complex types are interfaces; while your concrete types are just concrete classes.

You defined an API based on two interfaces: TransportBaseType and ConfigurationBaseType. TransportBaseType has a get/setConfiguration, which is a list of ConfigurationBaseType type.

You're trying to define a "reference" implementation for that API. You now have ActiveMQTransportType : TransportBaseType. However, you want to make sure that get/setConfiguration takes in a ConfigurationBaseTypeImpl, here defined as a concrete subtype of ConfigurationBaseType .

Your question could then be: i) how do I ensure my API accepts **only** a ConfigurationBaseTypeImpl for get/setConfiguration?, or ii) how do I ensure my API accepts a ConfigurationBaseTypeImpl for get/setConfiguration?

i) In **XSD 1.1**, you can achieve it with a helper type (I've based it on XSD 1.0, yet **XSD 1.0** doesn't work when <configuration> is repeating):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="ConfigurationBaseType" abstract="true">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ConfigurationBaseTypeImpl">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="ConfigurationBaseType">
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="configuration" type="ConfigurationBaseType"/>
    <xsd:element name="configurationImpl" type="ConfigurationBaseTypeImpl" substitutionGroup="configuration"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="TransportBaseType" abstract="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="configuration" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ActiveMQTransportTypeBase">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="TransportBaseType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="configurationImpl" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ActiveMQTransportType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="ActiveMQTransportTypeBase">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="broker" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="destination" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

ii) you don't have to do anything, really. In your XML file, simply add to the configuration element an xsi:type attribute pointing to your ConfigurationBaseTypeImpl, and you're done. It'll work just fine.

Comment: Petru,

I ended up going with a simplified schema with just one abstract type (for the transport types) and having the root element type reference the abstract type. It seems to be working as needed.

I don't fully understand the solution you provided for the first case.  I get the impression that the `substitutionGroup` attribute is a key part, although I don't know what that attribute or the restriction to `TransportBaseType` in the `ActiveMQTransportTypeBase` does.  Could you explain that more?

Thanks.

Comment: The first case restricts the type of configurations an ActiveMQ transport object works with. To do that, we need to create a "restriction" of the base type (ActiveMQTransportTypeBase). You also need additional fields, which means an "extension". Since only one subtyping mechanism may be used for a given type, the end result is truly a two-step (types) approach. The only way (I know) to override (not the one in XSD 1.1) the definition of an element through a restriction is by using substitution groups. If you're not familiar with substitution groups, and plan to do more XSD, I suggest read it.